# How to determine the kubernetes back-off period?

Tags: kubernetes

Considering that kubelet failed to perform some action - for instance pulling an image, the pod will go into a back-off state, for instance `ImagePullBackOff`, how do I determine when will it be retried? I understand that the back-off uses increasing time intervals for retrying. End it may eventually give up. Is there a clear algorithm so I can figure out the time to next attempt?

Apart from curiosity and ops convenience, it would help assess the self-healing recovery time needed.

Comment: Oh just to clarify... consider I have a failed rollout, something goes wrong, like image not published to registry (yet). Depending on how quickly I can notice and fix it, there will be the back-off interval on top of my remediation. This is what I'd like to get to.

Answer (score 2):

At any point, the maximum delay is 300s, that's a compiled-in constant.

See the [common info about ImagePullBackOff](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#imagepullbackoff):

> The BackOff part indicates that Kubernetes will keep trying to pull
> the image, with an increasing back-off delay.
>
> Kubernetes raises the delay between each attempt until it reaches a
> compiled-in limit, which is 300 seconds (5 minutes)

and the [restart policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy):

> After containers in a Pod exit, the kubelet restarts them with an
> exponential back-off delay (10s, 20s, 40s, …), that is capped at five
> minutes. Once a container has executed for 10 minutes without any
> problems, the kubelet resets the restart backoff timer for that
> container

I can't tell you more than in official documentation.

Comment: Thanks, that's very useful. So at any point, the maximum delay is 300s, that's a compiled-in constant. Why not add that to the answer? Links die and pages move...

The answer would be still better if we had some formula, let's say given X seconds from first failure, the back-off interval is N seconds and the next attempt will be in D seconds. 

I can assume the image pull is failing since creating a pod/deployment... not so much when a pod enters a crash loop. Is there a way to get to the internal counters?

Comment: Sorry, I have the same information as you now. I mean I can't say you more than in official documentation

Comment: I've edited the answer to make it useful to others and also in the future. That means also including the essential information to the text as links get broken over time. So, welcome to SO.